# PHPUnit and Xdebug coverage for abstract classes are always 0%

Tags: php, github, phpunit, xdebug

Repository for this concrete issue: [goph-R/dynart-coverage-test](https://github.com/goph-R/dynart-coverage-test)

The issue is as in the subject: for abstract classes I always get 0% coverage whatever I do.

- I created a `TheAbstractClass` and a related `TheAbstractClassTest`
- In the test I had to instantiate the abstract class, so I created a `TheTestableClass` for it and it extends the `TheAbstractClass`. I tried this with the PHPUnit's `createMockForAbstractClass()` the same issue happens.

After I run the tests, everything will PASS, but the coverage report for `TheAbstractClass` is 0%, but for `TheConcreteClass` it is 100%.

What I do wrong, how could I have coverage for my abstract classes?

My configuration:

- Windows 10
- PHP 7.4.3
- Xdebug 2.8.1
- PHPUnit 9.6.6

Comment: Skip the `-dauto_prepend_file=xdebug_filter.php` bit, you don't need it., and it's messing up your reporting.

Comment: This is the solution for me. Thanks! Can you write an answer so I can accept it? And I update my repo as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line test invocation includes this argument:

```
-dauto_prepend_file=xdebug_filter.php
```

Remove this, you don't need it, as the code coverage directory is already being provided by the `phpunit.xml.dist` file.